# Menu bar missing from LibreOffice apps after uninstalling xfce4-appmenu-plugin and its dependencies

Tags: linux, debian, libreoffice

I installed `xfce4-appmenu-plugin` out of curiosity but uninstalled it a few hours later because it keeps me from reaching the menus with keyboard shortcuts and it incurred considerable CPU overhead on my laptop, which made the fan spin faster and reduced battery life considerably.

Somehow, LibreOffice apps are now refusing to show their menu bar at all without the `appmenu` plugin thing.
[image: LibreOffice Calc missing menubar]

I have removed `~/.config/libreoffice` and reinstalled LibreOffice, but neither has worked so far.

*How do I get the menu bars back?*

I have LibreOffice 6.1 on Debian Testing.

Answer (score 0):

I use Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 4 so not clear if this works for you. But this same problem has been plaguing me for a while usually when themes change or installing some big graphics program changes some gtk settings.

Close any open libreoffice documents.
How i fixed was going to synaptic package manager and search the following libreoffice-gtk packages

`libreoffice-gtk`
`libreoffice-gtk2`
`libreoffice-gtk3`

Select all for *complete removal*.
After removal , select all for *reinstall*.
Sometimes it's installing only packages `libreoffice-gtk` and `libreoffice-gtk2` only that work.
Menus usually come back after.

This is a blunt quickfix for a reoccuring issue. So if someone can explain further why gtk changes screws up libreoffice menus it would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Xubuntu 19.04 here, hopefully this applies to other debian-based distros. After digging though config files for awhile I found that I was able to fix this by editing

`/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/org/appmenu.gtk-module-gschema.xml`

And changing the 20th line, under the key named `"always-show-inner-menu"`

to `<default>true</default>`

After logging out and in again, menu bars started showing up for apps which they were missing, such as LibreOffice and VLC media player